# Is there a way to programmatically control recording in a Mumble Client?

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Mumble on a Linux Ubuntu platform for VoIP calls.  I am wondering if there is a way to programmatically control recording in a Mumble Client, perhaps from a python script or C++ code.  I haven't been able to find anything out about an API for that.  Is there a way to do this?

I installed the Mumble Server and Clients in my system and I see how to configure then and start/stop recording in the Mumble UI (red button, provide path for recording, etc.).  It's all working fine.  I have searched online for an answer to this question but have not found anything.  I see the Mumble Server can be managed remotely but I can't record there.